# Installing OpenERP on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, odoo

Is there anything better than the [official documentation](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/install/linux/index.html) for installing OpenERP on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

[The Open Sourcerer](http://www.theopensourcerer.com/2011/04/19/how-to-install-openerp-6-on-ubuntu-10-04-lts-server-part-1/) described all the steps for installing manually from source, and [Iñaki Fernández](http://openerpappliance.com/2009/09/15/openerp-all-in-one-installer-update-for-dummies/) published a script for doing it all automatically.

I've used the script for several releases now, and it handles updates well. It just grabs the new revisions from a Launchpad branch.

I haven't tried the Open Sourcerer instructions, but I didn't notice anything obviously wrong when I read through them.